# What Collider should I use for my Player object?

Tags: c#, unity

I am making a 3rd person game with a simple orbit cam and it works fine most of the time, but since I have a box collider and I walk across an uneven surface, the player tends to tip over. How should I set it up so the player would not tip over anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a capsule collider, because it doesn't have edges and works great and also you could apply some constraints in the `Rigidbody`. It's common to apply.

Freeze position in: x and z

Freeze rotation in: x, y, and z

I hope that this will solve your problem.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. I had a Capsule collider before and thought about adding constraints but for some reason I decided to add a Box collider instead. I don't know why.